# Make the width of svg auto based on picture

Tags: svg

I downloaded [an svg-logo of zookeeper on wiki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apache_ZooKeeper_logo.svg).

It looks the following:

[Zookeeper svg-logo on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Mrmldsky/pen/JjWQqxE)

I removed text from logo, but the width is still the same, like it was with the text.

[Zookeeper svg-logo on codepen.io without text but with the same width](https://codepen.io/Mrmldsky/pen/OJpeeJa)

Is there a way to make the width get calculated based on the picture and to get rid of empty space?

I have already tried to remove `width="243.7mm"` from the second line, but this affects the whole ratio of image, not width.

Comment: Use this `viewBox="0 0 90.6 131.80"` for the svg element. Remove with and height. In order to know the values to use for the viewBox I've wrapped everithing in a group and get the bounding box with the getBBox() method

Comment: @enxaneta, thank you, that actually didn't helped to remove empty space, but moved picture to the center, I will use it, as far as i have no better alternative on the internet

Comment: Have you removed the width and the height of the svg element as I advized you in my previous comment?

Comment: @enxaneta, yes, it looks good in codepen, but in browser, it is a scroll-y